# How to use params in another action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im trying to do a little Restaurant-Website in Ruby on Rails(v. 3.2.13).

I made 3 tables: Customer(Name,Email), Reservation(customer_id,table_id), Table(seats,area).

My Models look like this.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :customer  
  belongs_to :table 
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :reservations  
  has_many :tables, :through => :reservations 
end

class Table < ActiveRecord::Base   
  has_many :reservations   
  has_many :customers, :through => :reservations 
end
```

I made a form for searching a suitable table. If the customer finds his table, he clicks a button to book it. This button leads to the "add a new customer" view. The button looks like this:

```
<%= button_to "Book table #{table.id}" , customers_path(:table_id => table) %>
```

In the `CustomerController`, I edited the create method like the following:

```
def create
  @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
  table = Table.find(params[:table_id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @customer.save
      format.html { redirect_to @customer, notice: 'Customer was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @customer, status: :created, location: @customer }
  @reservation = @customer.reservations.build(table: table).save!
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Sadly the "Table.find" does not work. When I use "Table.first" a Reservation is added, but when I use table like above I get the message: "Couldn't find Table with id=". I can, however, display the ID on the NewCustomer view.

Why is the ID not available in the `create` method?

EDIT:

Here is the form of the mainpage to search a table. Furthermore I have to say that i made a new resource mainpage for the table-search.

```
<%= form_tag mainpages_path, :method => 'get' do  %>
<p>
  How many persons: <br/><%= number_field_tag(:search) %> <br/>
  Date: <%= date_select :date, 'Date', use_short_month: true, order: [:day, :month, :year] %> <br/>
  Beginn: <%= time_select :Beginn, 'Beginn' , default:Time.now %>  <br/>
  End  : <%= time_select :Ende, 'Ende' , default: Time.now + 2.hours  %>  <br/>
  <%params[:search]%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
</p>
<% end %>

<% if @tables %>
<h2>Folgende Tische stehen zur Auswahl</h1>
<% @tables.each do |table| %>
    <div class="entry" >
      <h3>Seats: <%= table.seats %></h3>
      <h3>Area: <%= table.area %></h3>
      <%= link_to "Book this table #{table.id}" , new_customer_path(:table_id => table) %>
    </div>
<% end %>
<% else %>
<p> Pls choose a table</p>
<% end %>
```

EDIT2:
The link to HTML-Code:

```
<a href="/customers/new?table_id=1" mode="post">Book this table 1</a>
```

And here is the HTML-Code of the customer/new-view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Restaurant</title>
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/customers.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/mainpages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/reservations.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/tables.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/customers.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/mainpages.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/reservations.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/tables.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="ej1MgV2fad014SLkCv3dZXl8TknQH4JHZLoe56Xn/Kk=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>New customer</h1>

<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/customers" class="new_customer" id="new_customer"   method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ej1MgV2fad014SLkCv3dZXl8TknQH4JHZLoe56Xn/Kk=" /></div>
<div class="field">
<label for="customer_name">Name</label><br />
<input id="customer_name" name="customer[name]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="field">
<label for="customer_email">Email</label><br />
<input id="customer_email" name="customer[email]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>


<input id="table_id" name="table_id" type="hidden" />


<div class="actions">
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Customer" />
</div>
</form>
<a href="/customers">Back</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are the routes for customers in routes.rb?

Comment: just ` resources :customers `

Comment: @Mike just do 'rake routes' at the root of your application, and paste the output here.

Comment: customers   GET    /customers(.:format)             customers#index
            POST   /customers(.:format)             customers#create
new_customer GET    /customers/new(.:format)         customers#new
edit_customer GET    /customers/:id/edit(.:format)    customers#edit
     customer GET    /customers/:id(.:format)         customers#show
             PUT    /customers/:id(.:format)        customers#update
             DELETE /customers/:id(.:format)       customers#destroy  I dont know how to format it in the comment field

Answer (score 1):

change in the controller (just add an@ symbol)

```
@table = Table.find(params[:table_id])
```

in view

```
<%= button_to "Book table #{table.id}" , customers_path(:table_id => @table) %>
```

Comment: I edited my code like yours but the error message doesnt change

Comment: <%= button_to "Book table #{table.id}" , customers_path(:table_id => @table), :method => :post %>

Comment: Still the same. Why should I try the post method?

Comment: To access the customer#create action you have to submit a POST request to customers_path.

Comment: @Nick and everyone else :)   I can see the table_id in the customer/new view. i can display it with ´<p>Table ID=<%= :table_id%></p>´ but as soon as i click on create customer the table_id isnt available anymore.

Comment: Try this:  

`<%= button_to "Book table #{table.id}" , customers_path(:table_id => table.id), :method => :post %>`

Comment: @Mike Do you get that when you click the button or before the button even renders?  I have no idea where `/customers/new` is coming from.  Can you run `rails console` and type `puts app.customers_path`?

Comment: @Nick I got this error after clicking on the booking-button. Here is the rails console: ´irb(main):002:0> puts app.customers_path´
´/customers´
´=> nil´

Comment: @Nick any further ideas?

Comment: @Mike, one more thing I would want to take a look at is the actual HTML produced by the `button_to`.  Can you copy the entire <form> it generates from the html source and put it in your original post?

Comment: @Nick i copied the form to the original post

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
<%= button_to "Book table #{table.id}" , customers_path(:table_id => table), method: :post %>
```

Comment: Doesnt work. I got this msg: No route matches [POST] "/customers/new"

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the use of `button_to`...

From the [Url Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html) documentation:
`Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options.`

The action attribute of the form needs to look similar to this:

`/customers/new?table_id=<table_id>`

When you click this button it should route to the Customer `new` action that renders the `new` view. You need to pass `table_id` to the `new` view and then add it to your Customer form. Something like this:

```
def new
  ...
  @table_id = params[:table_id]
end
```

Then, when you submit the Customer `form` - which will route to the `create` action, you should have access to `params[:table_id]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But your change of the new action did not help. The same error as before. Btw the Request Parameters listed below the error message:  ´{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"zNaQMcLy2NR2NaYqgpZIBP9sqKr2od9+y3pQRfwQcyY=",
 "customer"=>{"name"=>"mike",
 "email"=>"mike@trololo.com"},
 "table_id"=>"",
 "commit"=>"Create Customer"}´

Comment: Should i change the button_to to link_to? Or is there no difference?

Comment: Great, thanks for the the params, they help. Could you please paste your `new` view?

Comment: Well it is the standard scaffold generated new view that renders the _form.html.erb. And this form is still the standard scaffold form too.

Comment: Great - so you need to add the `table_id` field to that form; otherwise, the controller action `create` will never know about the param `table_id` - hence your problem...

Comment: OK I forgot one thing. My bad sry. I added ´ <%= hidden_field_tag :table_id %> ´ to the new customer form before. Without that hidden_field I got the err msg: `Couldn't find Table without an ID` . And with the hidden_field the msg is: `Couldn't find Table with id=` . Is it enough to display the variable like I do?

Comment: Getting closer. :) Try `<%= hidden_field_tag :table_id, @table_id %>`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last bit of code you posted, you need to have:

```
<%= link_to "Book this table #{table.id}" , customer_path(:table_id => table), mode: :post %>
```

Comment: I added your change but sadly the err msg doesnt change.

Comment: Can you post the actual HTML generated by the `link_to`?  Not the ERB, but the actual html that results after the page is loaded.

Comment: I added the HTML code of the `link_to` and of the cuustomer/new-view

Answer (score 0):

Hello after 1 million tries I found the mistake! The solution with the hidden_field_tag was partly correct. All the time I tried `<%= hidden_field_tag :table_id %>` . But with this code the create action knows the variable `:table_id` but it has an empty string. Now I added `params[:table_id]` to the hidden_field and now the value of the variable `:table_id` is availlable.

Long story made short, variable name AND value have to be in the `hidden_field_tag`!

`<%= hidden_field_tag :table_id, params[:table_id] %>`

Thanks to everyone who tried helping me!