# Rails How to validate time and date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, time

Hi Im stil trying to do a little Restaurant-Website in Ruby on Rails(v. 3.2.13).

Here you can see my current configuration: [How to use params in another action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18217396/how-to-use-params-in-another-action)

Right now it is possible to book a table, but there is no validation. I think i have to validate the start-time, the end-time and the date in the form_tag like the following:

- Start-time has to be in the future
- A new reservation cant be done on the same day between Start- and End-time
- End-time is fixed to Start-time + 2 hours
- The date has to be in the future or the same day

Ok End-time should not be validated. Every reservation lasts 2 hours so I just have to allocate the value Start-time+2 hours.

I tried it with the `time_select`and `date_select` but the format looks very odd (5i,4i,...) and I couldnt do anything with this.

Should I use gem for validation? Is it possible to sum times(Start-time +2 hours)? Can I use another format for time/date? Did i forget any further aspects to validate?

I dont know how to continue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

k i finally did it with Regex

```
t=params[:Starttime].scan(/\d\d/)
my_time = t[0] << ":" << t[1] << ":00"
Time.zone.parse(my_time)
```

this is the ref to the  [Time.zone.parse](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-create)
this will finally give you the time object that you want.
Please notify me if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [validates_timeliness gem](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/) It keeps your models clean and intuitive and supports I18n localization with flexible error messages for various date/time comparisons.

```
validates_datetime :starts_at, :after => :now
validates_datetime :ends_at, :on_or_after => :two_days_later, :if => :starts_at

def two_days_later
  self.starts_at + 2.hours
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the defult format that is given by the form from which you have picked the date using this parse function and it will return you a date object in ruby. then you can apply all the validations you want very easily.

```
 Date.parse(yourDate.to_s)
```

for checking in future there is a direct method as `date_object.future?` so you can check with that.
and yeah it is possible to sum times in rails you can do `your_time + 2.hours` for adding 2 hours to the time.

Comment: if you need further help with the queries please ask.

Comment: I think i need further help :). That is my time_select: `<%= time_select :Starttime , 'Starttime', default: Time.now, minute_step: 15, :ignore_date => true %>`. So I save the time in the variable `:starttime`. And in the controller I tried `@Start = @Start.parse(:Starttime.to_s)` But thats not working

Comment: you got it a bit wrong, use `@Start = Date.parse(params[:Starttime].to_s)` you cannot use starttime directly its not a variable in your controller you have to access it through `params`

Comment: Ok thx I changed the code but now the err msg is `invalid date`

Comment: Ok the error seems legit because its a time_select not a date_select. But using Time.parse returns the error `no time information in ""`

Comment: I am really sorry You will have to use the `Time` class instead of date, i thought you were taking the date as input. My apologies. so please use `Time.parse(params[:Starttime].to_s)`

Comment: I found the mistake. After the page is loaded :Starttime has no value. I changed my code like this: `if params[:Starttime]
    @Start = Time.parse(params[:Starttime].to_s)
    end`.

Comment: The times are working but the date is now the problem. I use date_select in the form:  `<%= date_select :date, 'date', use_short_month: true, order: [:day, :month, :year] %> <br/>` and in the controller `@Bookingdate = Date.parse(params[:date].to_s)` but `invalid date` appears

Comment: The parse function does not work properly... If I use this function it just formats the realtime and not the value I selected in the time_select. Do you know why?

Comment: if you are taking both date and time you should rather use the `DateTime` class. and by the date parse for Date works correctly i have used it to input date of birth in my application.

Comment: try printing the string that you are passing to the parse and show it here.

Comment: string of params[:starttime]: `{"Starttime(4i)"=>"08", "Starttime(5i)"=>"28"}` output of Time.parse(params[:Starttime].to_s): `2013-08-16 13:30:08 +0200`

Comment: are these 08 ans 28 the hour and minute that u selected and the resulting time is the time that is currently at your location?

Comment: also try using `Time.zone.parse`

Comment: exactly! Maybe the if params[:Starttime] sets the value to the current time after loading the time_select field

Comment: one time pls print `params[:Starttime].class` and `params[:Starttime].to_s` and tell me what prints

Comment: Time.zone.parse just changed the hour value to -2 hours to the current time

Comment: params[:Starttime].class =ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess, params[:Starttime].to_s ={"Starttime(4i)"=>"08","Starttime(5i)"=>"51"}

Comment: okay one last thing just print these `params[:Starttime][:4i]` and `params[:Starttime][:5i]`

Comment: if the give the value as `08` and `51` or i mean whatever u select then use this 
    `my_time = params[:Starttime][:4i] << ':' << params[:Starttime][:5i] << ':00'` 
    `Time.zone.parse(my_time)`

Comment: have a look here for ref http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-c-create
or ask me if it still doesn't work.

Comment: `params[:Starttime][:4i]` and `params[:Starttime][:5i]` do not work . err msg `syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END`

Comment: what about this 
`params[:Starttime].select {|k,v| k =~ /^Starttime/ }.
  sort.map {|f| f.last.to_s }.join(':')`

Comment: i added your code to the view and now its correct now. But how can i use this?

Comment: you wanted the Date and Time objects, now you have them, what else do you need? I have written in the original answer on how to manipulate the date and time objects according to your need.